# Want to make a Sharepoint website which will show my Employee the stock

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft365

I am a newbie in SharePoint and the microsoft Ecosystem. I was thinking about creating a sharepoint Website where my Employees can see my stock from there mobile phones which i update in an excel sheet in 365, Or some other usecase can also work apart from taking data from excel. But the only issue is that the stock will be updated 4 times in a single day. Would love it if someone would guide me in this.

Thank you so much in advance.

I did try SharePoint and embed my excel sheet directly to the website but that takes too much time to load on mobile phones and its not optimized for mobile screen as well.

Comment: You can try using SharePoint list directly. https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59